# Conversion from bson.Document to JsObject and applying reads on it with joda.DateTime

Tags: mongodb, scala, datetime, playframework

I am currently integrating part of our system with MongoDB and we decided to use the official scala driver for it.

We have case class with joda.DateTime as parameters:

```
case class Schema(templateId: Muid,
                      createdDate: DateTime,
                      updatedDate: DateTime,
                      columns: Seq[Column])
```

We also defined format for it:

```
implicit lazy val checklistSchemaFormat : Format[Schema] = (
        (__ \ "templateId").format[Muid] and
            (__ \ "createdDate").format[DateTime] and
            (__ \ "updatedDate").format[DateTime] and
            (__ \ "columns").format[Seq[Column]]
        )((Schema.apply _), unlift(Schema.unapply))
```

When I serialize this object to json and write to mongo, the `createdDate` and `updatedDate` getting converted to `Long` (which is technically fine). And this is how we do it:

```
val bsonDoc = Document(Json.toJson(schema).toString())

    collection(DbViewSchemasCollectionName).replaceOne(filter, bsonDoc, new UpdateOptions().upsert(true)).subscribe(new Observer[UpdateResult] {
      override def onNext(result: UpdateResult): Unit = logger.info(s"Successfully updates checklist template schema with result: $result")
      override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = logger.info(s"Failed to update checklist template schema with error: $e")
      override def onComplete(): Unit = {}
    })
```

as a result Mongo has this type of object:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("56fc4247eb3c740d31b04f05"),
  "templateId": "gaQP3JIB3ppJtro9rO9BAw",
  "createdDate": NumberLong(1459372615507),
  "updatedDate": NumberLong(1459372615507),
  "columns": [
  ...
  ]
}
```

Now, I am trying to read it like so:

```
collection(DbViewSchemasCollectionName).find(filter).first().head() map { document =>
        ChecklistSchema.checklistSchemaFormat reads Json.parse(document.toJson()) match {
          case JsSuccess(value, _) => {
            Some(value)
          }
          case JsError(e) => throw JsResultException(e)
        }
    } recover { case e =>
      logger.info("ERROR " + e)
      None
    }
```

And at this point the reads always failing, since the `createdDate` and `updatedDate` now look like this:

> "createdDate" : { "$numberLong" : "1459372615507" },  "updatedDate" :
>   {"$numberLong" : "1459372615507" }

How do I deal with this situation? Is there any easier conversion between `bson.Document` and `JsObject`? Or I am completely digging into the wrong direction...

Thanks,

Comment: You may implement simple json transformer `bson schema` -> `scala case class schema` and after trasformation read to `Schema` with `Json format macros`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach to resolve your issue. 
Firstly, I used [json4s](http://json4s.org/) for reading the writing json to case classes

example:

```
case class User(_id: Option[Int], username: String, firstName: String, createdDate: DateTime , updatedDate: DateTime )


 // A small wapper to convert case class to Document 
  def toBson[A <: AnyRef](x : A):Document = {
   val json = write[A](x)
     Document(json) }


def today() = DateTime.now

val user = User(Some(212),"binkabir","lacmalndl", today , today)

val bson = toBson(user)

usersCollection.insertOne(bson).subscribe((x: Completed) => println(x))

val f = usersCollection.find(equal("_id",212)).toFuture()

f.map(_.head.toJson).map( x => read[User](x)).foreach(println)
```

The code above will create a user case class, convert to Document, save to mongo db, query the db and print the returned User case class

I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question (`bson.Document` <-> `JsObject`) - YES; this is a solved problem, check out [Play2-ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/play2.html), which makes it seem like you're storing/retrieving `JsObject` instances - plus it's fully asynchronous and super-easy to get going in a Play application.

You can even go a step further and use a library like [Mondrian](https://github.com/themillhousegroup/mondrian) (full disclosure: *I wrote it!*) to get the basic CRUD operations on top of ReactiveMongo for your Play-JSON domain case-classes.

Obviously I'm biased, but I think these solutions are a great fit if you've already defined your models as case classes in Play - you can forget about the whole `BSONDocument` family and stick to `Json._` and `JsObject` etc that you already know well.

**EDIT:**
At the risk of *further* downvotes, I will demonstrate how I would go about storing and retrieving the OP's `Schema` object, using **Mondrian**. I'm going to show pretty-much *everything* for completeness; bear in mind you've actually already done most of this. Your final code *will* have fewer lines than your current code, as you'd expect when you use a library.

#### Model Objects

There's a `Column` class here that's never mentioned, for simplicity let's just say that's:

```
case class Column (name:String, width:Int)
```

Now we can get on with the `Schema`, which is just:

```
import com.themillhousegroup.mondrian._

case class Schema(_id: Option[MongoId],
                  createdDate: DateTime,
                  updatedDate: DateTime,
                  columns: Seq[Column]) extends MongoEntity
```

So far, we've just implemented the `MongoEntity` trait, which just required the `templateId` field to be renamed and given the required type.

#### JSON Converters

```
import com.themillhousegroup.mondrian._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

object SchemaJson extends MongoJson {
  implicit lazy val columnFormat = Json.format[Column]

  // Pick one - easy:
  implicit lazy val schemaFormat = Json.format[Schema]

  // Pick one - backwards-compatible (uses "templateId"):
  implicit lazy val checklistSchemaFormat : Format[Schema] = (
    (__ \ "templateId").formatNullable[MongoId] and
    (__ \ "createdDate").format[DateTime] and
    (__ \ "updatedDate").format[DateTime] and
    (__ \ "columns").format[Seq[Column]]
  )((Schema.apply _), unlift(Schema.unapply))
}
```

The JSON converters are standard Play-JSON stuff; we pick up the `MongoId` `Format` by extending `MongoJson`. I've shown two different ways of defining the `Format` for `Schema`. If you have clients out in the wild using `templateId` (or if you prefer it) then use the second, more verbose declaration.

#### Service layer

For brevity I'll skip the application-configuration, you can read the [Mondrian README.md](https://github.com/themillhousegroup/mondrian) for that. Let's define the `SchemaService` that is responsible for persistence operations on `Schema` instances:

```
import com.themillhousegroup.mondrian._
import SchemaJson._

class SchemaService extends TypedMongoService[Schema]("schemas")
```

That's it. We've linked the model object, the name of the MongoDB collection (`"schemas"`) and (implicitly) the necessary converters.

#### Saving a `Schema` and finding a `Schema` based on some criteria

Now we start to realize the value of Mondrian. `save` and `findOne` are standard operations - we get them for free in our `Service`, which we inject into our controllers in the standard way:

```
class SchemaController @Inject (schemaService:SchemaService) extends Controller {

   ...
   // Returns a Future[Boolean]
   schemaService.save(mySchema).map { saveOk =>
     ...
   }
   ...


   ...
   // Define a filter criteria using standard Play-JSON:
   val targetDate = new DateTime()
   val criteria = Json.obj("createdDate" -> Json.obj("$gt" ->targetDate.getMillis))


   // Returns a Future[Option[Schema]]
   schemaService.findOne(criteria).map { maybeFoundSchema =>
      ...
   }
}
```

So there we go. No sign of the `BSON` family, just the Play JSON that, as you say, we all know and love. You'll only need to reach for the Mongo documentation when you need to [construct a JSON query](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) (that `$gt` stuff) although in some cases you can use Mondrian's overloaded `findOne(example:Schema)` method if you are just looking for a simple object match, and avoid even that :-)

Comment: Your answer is to make him change the library?

Comment: He asked if there was an easier way to convert between the two worlds. There is, but it requires an additional library.

Comment: "you've already defined your models as case classes in Play - you can forget about the whole BSONDocument family and stick to Json._ and JsObject etc that you already know well."  - That was exactly my question, how do I do it with a simple JsObject that we all know and love?